# What does Deadpool mean in this comic book page?

Tags: marvel, comics, deadpool

On [this comic book page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fo5fm.jpg), Deadpool says

> I guess if you want to do something right...you've got to do it over and over again until it sticks.

[image: comic book page described above]

Does this mean that the only true end to a battle is a permanent end, and by definition, an end that is not permanent is not really an end at all?

Comment: Given the context of the quote presumably he's talking about killing Wolverine.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot based on what you said I think that Deadpool is saying that even Wolverine can't heal from an infinite number of injuries (the result of using lethal blows on him over and over again), and since it would "stick" then Wolverine would die. Am I correct in extrapolating that no one, even Wolverine, with his healing factor, cannot complete infinite tasks (i.e. healing from infinite strikes)?

Comment: "the only true end to a battle is a permanent end" — that sentence doesn't really make sense. A temporary end isn't an end: it's a pause, or an intermission.

Answer (score 4):

That page is from [Deadpool kills the Marvel Universe](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Deadpool_Kills_the_Marvel_Universe_Vol_1_1). Where Deadpool is... well, you get the idea. And Deadpool being Deadpool, he's referring to something beyond the fourth wall: Wolverine's popularity as a Marvel character. Cropped out the gorier bits but sticking it behind a spoiler anyways in case you don't like blood (spoiler alert: he kills Wolverine). Typed up his speech below, sans bloody end.

> But see... I killed you once... and I bet you'll come back again... no matter how many times I slaughter you. Your tendency to come back from the brink of death has nothing to do with your healing factor. Your mutant power isn't regeneration. It's popularity. But don't worry. I've got big plans... and all the popularity in the world can't save you this time!

> [image]